# How to load a controller function and render it in a twig tag using Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2 and Twig. I have a function (below) in my controller that returns a specific text. Is it possible to call that function directly from my template and change the {{text}} in my template to whatever the function returns, possibly via Ajax?

Here's my function:

```
public function generateCode($url) {
    $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/embed/' . $url;
    $return = '<iframe>'.$url.'</iframe>';
    return $return;
}
```

Another controller function calls the function above and renders my template:

```
public function getCodeAction($url) {
    $text = $this->generateCode($url);
    return $this->render('MyMyBundle:User:code.html.twig', array('text' => $text));
}
```

In my template I am using:

```
{{ text }}
```

to display the value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use ajax if you have dynamic data, but as far as I can see from your brief info, you can always execute that controller function directly from your view:

```
{% render "MyMyBundle:User:generateCode" with { 'url': 'your url here' } %}
```

More Information on this available at: 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_view.html, under Embedding other Controllers

Comment: Thanks. It worked, I just had to play around with the render method a little - now even Ajax works smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike What do you mean with playing around?

Answer (score 36):

In Symfony 2.2, this was changed.

> The render tag signature and arguments changed.
>
> Before:
>
> `{% render 'BlogBundle:Post:list' with { 'limit': 2 }, { 'alt': BlogBundle:Post:error' } %}`
>
> After:
>
> `{% render controller('BlogBundle:Post:list', { 'limit': 2 }), { 'alt': 'BlogBundle:Post:error' } %}`
>
> or
>
> `{{ render(controller('BlogBundle:Post:list', { 'limit': 2 }), { 'alt': 'BlogBundle:Post:error'}) }}`
>
> Note: The function is the preferred way.

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/UPGRADE-2.2.md

Comment: to avoid any confusion: `{{ render(controller(... }}` is the function

Answer (score 9):

For the record, in new versions you need to use the absolute URL:

```
{{ render url('my_route_id', {'param': value}) }}
```

Answer (score 7):

{{ render(controller("AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:topArticles", {'num': 10})) }}

Answer (score 4):

In Silex I solved it like this:

```
{{ render(url('route_name', {'param': value})) }}
```

If you do not have the route name, URL can be used:

```
{{ render(app.request.baseUrl ~ '/some-path/' ~ value) }}
```

If using URL we should always concat the baseUrl.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony 2.6+

in twig:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:PropertySearch:featuredProperties', {'limit': 15})) }}
```

controller:

```
/**
 * featuredPropertiesAction
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @param int $limit
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function featuredPropertiesAction(Request $request, $limit)
{
    $search = $this->resultsHelper->featuredSearch($limit);

    return $this->render('HASearchBundle::featured_properties.html.twig', [
        'search' => $search,
    ]);
}
```