# Symfony2 - Twig Function returning an array

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I created a twig extension that returns me the list of all the blogs I have. This list is an array that I loop through in my twig template.

**Here's my extension:**

```
<?php
// src/OSC/BlogBundle/Twig/BlogsListExtension.php
namespace OSC\BlogBundle\Twig;

class BlogsListExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'blogsList' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, array($this, 'blogsList')),
        );
    }



    public function blogsList()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager();
        $repository = $em
            ->getRepository('OSCBlogBundle:Blog');


        $blogs = $repository->findBy(array('visibleState' => true));
        usort($blogs, array("\OSC\BlogBundle\Controller\BlogController", "orderBlogByTitle"));


        return $blogs;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'osc_BlogsListExtension';
    }
}
```

**Here's what I added in my services.yml**

```
services:
    osc_blog.blogsList_extension:
        class: OSC\BlogBundle\Twig\BlogsListExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**In my twig template, I want to do the following:**

```
<ul>
        {% for blog in blogsList()|sort %}
         <li><a href="{{ path('osc_blog_homepage', {'blogId': blog.id })}}"><span>{{ blog.title }}</span></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

**I get the following error:**

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("Notice: Array to string conversion

**Finally, my question is how can I pass an array to a variable in order to loop through it in a twig template ?**

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What would be the output of `var_dump($blogs)`? Is it an array at all? Also why there is a double sorting? First in the php file (useort) and then another one in for statement.

Comment: $blogs is an array that returns all the blog objects

Comment: Is the posted code your entire twig template?

Comment: @mattexx no, it is not. But that's the only thing that changed before stopping to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should happen because `blogsList()` returns an `ArrayCollection`, wich acts as an array, but it is not.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/792), you should just do:

```
public function blogsList()
{
    // ...
    return $blogs->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Even after doing what you proposed (clearing the cache as well), I still get the same error... Why is it telling me that I want to convert an array to a string ?

Comment: Pretty strange - be sure to be dealing with a proper array, consider then returning a mock of the data you want in order to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Before, I was just passing the variable blogs to every template but it was getting heavy and code was getting duplicated each time. But, when passing blogs and looping through it (without using the toArray), it worked...

Comment: FYK, [you can render a controller action inside another template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289513/how-to-load-a-controller-function-and-render-it-in-a-twig-tag-using-symfony2).