# Symfony access form in all views

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a login/register form in the app.

```
namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', 'text', ['label' => 'Username']);
        $builder->add('email', 'hidden', ['label' => 'Email']);
        $builder->add('password', 'password',['label' => 'Password']);

        $builder->add('cancel', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'CANCEL'
        ]);

        $builder->add('register', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'CREATE ACCOUNT'
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'register';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\User',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want this available in all pages hence I want form markup to be placed in `base.html.twig`

My question is, what is the Symfony recommended way of doing it? I don't want to keep passing the form in each and every action of the controller.

How do I got about it? by defining the service? any example or pointer is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have a dedictaed contoller that handles the form.
You can then call this controller action from twig directly, adding the controller call into your main layout.html.twig.

E.g.

```
{% render controller('AppBundle:Login:form') %}
```

And the controller something like;

```
class LoginController extends Controller 
{
  public function form(Request $request)
  {
    // create your form

    // return html of form
  }
}
```

Ref: [How to load a controller function and render it in a twig tag using Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289513/how-to-load-a-controller-function-and-render-it-in-a-twig-tag-using-symfony2) - look at answer by @Blowski

A registration example;

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Security;

use AppBundle\Entity\User,
    AppBundle\Form\Entity\UserType;
use \Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="user_registration")
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        // 1) build the form
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

        // 2) handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            // 4) save the User!
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            // ... do any other work - like sending them an email, etc
            // maybe set a "flash" success message for the user

            return $this->redirectToRoute('replace_with_some_route');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:security:register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming I also want this for registration, where do we handle the logic for  registration?

Comment: I would just create a contoller, eg RegistrationController that has functions that handles user registration. Then you can use the twig controller function to call the required action. Will update answer

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that it is Ajax form. regardless I now got a clue on how to go. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You mean passing an instance of `FormView` made from your `RegisterType`?

I think most easily you can create Twig extension that'll register `FormBuilder` as its dependency and will expose a function (or maybe even a global variable) with the form view. Then you can also use just one instance of form view and use it multiple times if you wish.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html